# TFS Dual-Tier on Azure with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, tfs, active-directory

So, I'm trying to setup TFS 2017 on Azure with separate App tier VM and DB tier VM. I'm trying to connect them but apparently you can only do multi-tier when in an AD. Am I able to use solely Azure Active Directory for this? If so, how do I set it up? I've not see any instructions on how to properly do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is similar to [this case](https://serverfault.com/questions/775049/host-tfs-on-azure) on ServerFault. Usually, you need follow the steps below:

1. create virtual network
2. put your vms into that virtual network so they will be in the same network and domain works
3. join the domain
4. install TFS AT server and DT server.

Note: If you get error An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain “x.x.com” could not be contacted when join a Windows 2012 R2 server to a domain in Windows Azure, check the solution here: http://www.itexperience.net/2014/06/06/an-active-directory-domain-controller-ad-dc-for-the-domain-x-x-com-could-not-be-contacted-windows-azure/

Useful guide can be downloaded from: http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/842516